# Next.js global variables on server and client based on request domain

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am working on a Next.js multisite scoped project and I need to create a set of global variables to use on client and server (during SSR) side.

So far I came to the below solution.

This is how my custom App looks like:

```
import App from 'next/app'
import multisite from '@utils/multisite';
import MultisiteProvider from '@components/multisite/MultisiteProvider';

function MyApp({
  Component,
  site,
  pageProps
}) {
  // Will add site props to every page
  const props = { ...pageProps, site };
  return (
    // Provider will enable a hook to get site props on any child component
    <MultisiteProvider site={ site } >
      <Component { ...props }/>
    </MultisiteProvider>
  )
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async(appContext) => {
  // getInitialProps executes on every page access, even on client when using "next/link"

  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);
  let host;
  if (appContext.ctx.req) {
    // Get host from request during SSR
    host = appContext.ctx.req.headers.host;
  } else {
    // Get host from window on client
    host = window.location.host;
  }

  return {
    ...appProps,
    site: await multisite.resolveSiteProps(host)
  };
}

export default MyApp;
```

I would like to avoid using getInitialProps because it was supposed to disable Automatic Static Optimization in pages without Static Generation (which is my case). As mentioned on [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app#caveats)

The variables for each site are located on a "sites" directory under root folder like this:

```
/sites
--/siteone.com.us.json
--/siteone.com.br.json
--/sitetwo.com.us.json
```

And there is a function used to load the right file based on the current request domain.

```
const resolveSiteProps = async(host) => {
  const domain = normalizeDomain(host);
  const site = await
  import (
    /* webpackChunkName: "site-prefs" */
    /* webpackMode: "lazy" */
    `../sites/${domain}`
  );
  return {
    ...site.default,
    domain
  };
}
```

It would be nice if I could resolve this variables once during SSR and just use them in the client side.

I am looking for some helpful and elegant ideas to solve this case. Any thoughts?

Comment: What's not working with your current approach? What's the actual problem?

Comment: Actually it works fine. I was wondering if I could do that with a less intrusive approach. Without handling it with React or the Next fetch data API, just creating some env like variables.

Answer (score 1):

Only tried this solution really quickly, but this should work at least in theory but is a different approach. We use rewrites based on host, but for a slightly different problem. Additionally, we do have a similar solution that you posted originally for deciding the brand based on request host.

What if you would have different paths for each site, and then use a rewrite in next.config.js based on the host?

Steps:

1. add subfolders for each site in the pages, such as pages/siteone and pages/sitetwo
2. Add rewrites based on site host as shown below

```
async rewrites() {
{
        source: '/:path*',
        destination: '/siteone/:path',
        has: [
          {
            type: 'host',
            value: 'siteone.com.us',
          },
        ],
      },
}
```

Of course this comes with a cost of having to have all the pages for each site, but you can share most of the code, so hopefully that's not an issue.

Note: this is probably not a fully functional example, but at least it gives you a hint about what could be possible with rewrites in Next.js.

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites

Comment: Hi, I understand the premise. Thank you for sharing. However, your answer is a bit more specific to rewriting a request. This question is not about rewriting a request or redirection. The question is about creating a server-and-client-accessible-object based off of request data.

Be that as it may, since you have already answered, I would like to ask (maybe you have encountered): let's say I want a dynamic `destination` based on some other variable. Is this possible with `next.config.js` `rewrite`?

Comment: Alright. I think with rewrites, the only options you have are these has objects as documented here: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites#header-cookie-and-query-matching

Answer (score 1):

Mainly There is two ways to do this:

1. **Create dynamic `_sites/[site]` route in the pages folder and then use `rewrites` to normalize your URLs.**

   You can find full implementation here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12848#discussioncomment-1551776

   downsides:

   - you will have to explicitly include list of your domains in `getStaticProps` in all the pages you want static generated.
   - `pathname` in next `useRouter` will always include the prefix `_sites/[site]`.
   - based on personal experience `_sites/[site]` prefix will sometimes appear actual website urls and cause errors.

---

- **Branch off of your main and deploy each branch separately. (RECOMMENDED)**

  Create `.env` file and add `NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN=my-domain` then create a new production branch from `main` and change the variable like this: `NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN=my-second-domain`. you can access this variable wherever in your application, as stated in the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser)

  downside:

  - You will have to manually merge your `main` branch to other branches that you create for each domain. This solution will not scale if you have many domains.

note: you cannot use `_middleware` for static optimization. The reason is static files are created at build time and cannot figure out which domain will make the requests.